# "encoded string too long" error in play stage command

Tags: playframework-2.1

Using play framework v2.1.1, we use command

```
play clean compile stage
```

to generate deployable artifacts. It was working fine from past many months. We have not changed anything but now when I tried same command again, it's throwing error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: encoded string too long: 65909 bytes
at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27)
at scala.Predef$.error(Predef.scala:123)
at sbinary.JavaUTF$StringFormat$.writes(javaprotocol.scala:165)
at sbinary.JavaUTF$StringFormat$.writes(javaprotocol.scala:100)
at sbt.InputCache$$anon$1.write(SeparatedCache.scala:27)
at sbt.HListCacheImplicits$$anon$12.write(Cache.scala:185)
at sbt.HListCacheImplicits$$anon$12.write(Cache.scala:173)
at sbt.HListCacheImplicits$$anon$12.write(Cache.scala:186)
at sbt.HListCacheImplicits$$anon$12.write(Cache.scala:173)
at sbt.HListCacheImplicits$$anon$12.write(Cache.scala:186)
at sbt.HListCacheImplicits$$anon$12.write(Cache.scala:173)
at sbt.Tracked$CacheHelp$$anonfun$save$1.apply(Tracked.scala:68)
at sbt.Tracked$CacheHelp$$anonfun$save$1.apply(Tracked.scala:68)
at sbt.Using.apply(Using.scala:25)
at sbt.Tracked$CacheHelp.save(Tracked.scala:68)
at sbt.Tracked$$anonfun$inputChanged$1.apply(Tracked.scala:48)
at sbt.Doc$class.cached(Doc.scala:55)
at sbt.Scaladoc.cached(Doc.scala:58)
at sbt.Defaults$$anonfun$docTaskSettings$1.apply(Defaults.scala:546)
at sbt.Defaults$$anonfun$docTaskSettings$1.apply(Defaults.scala:540)
at sbt.Scoped$$anonfun$hf5$1.apply(Structure.scala:581)
at sbt.Scoped$$anonfun$hf5$1.apply(Structure.scala:581)
at scala.Function1$$anonfun$compose$1.apply(Function1.scala:49)
at sbt.Scoped$Reduced$$anonfun$combine$1$$anonfun$apply$12.apply(Structure.scala:311)
at sbt.Scoped$Reduced$$anonfun$combine$1$$anonfun$apply$12.apply(Structure.scala:311)
at sbt.$tilde$greater$$anonfun$$u2219$1.apply(TypeFunctions.scala:41)
at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$5.work(System.scala:71)
at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:232)
at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:232)
at sbt.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:18)
at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:238)
at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:232)
at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:232)
at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4$$anonfun$1.apply(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:160)
at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:30)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

[error] (compile:doc) encoded string too long: 65909 bytes
[error] Total time: 3 s, completed 7 Feb, 2017 5:35:58 PM
```

I have setup play again, clean all required directories but still no success. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you ever manage to fix this issue? I have started to get the same error on an old build.

Comment: @StephenMurby sorry, never got chance to actually solve it. did you solved it?

Comment: Hey guys, any update on this? I am stuck in similar situation. It works on my local dev machine, but fails on jenkins. I am suspecting its an environment issue, do I need to specify some writeUTF limits for java ?

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this issue by removing generation of java api docs. Here is what I added to my build.sbt file:

```
publishArtifact in (Compile, packageDoc) := false
publishArtifact in packageDoc := false
sources in (Compile,doc) := Seq.empty
```